# include single directory in an archive with gradle Zip task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a directory A under my project's rootDir. Directory A has subidrectories B,C,D,E,etc.

I want to create archive of only B and ignore others. I have written a gradle task to zip the directory B.

```
task ZipOnlyB(type: Zip){
archiveName = "ArchiveOfB.zip"
destinationDir = file ("${rootDir}/toSendToArtifactory")

from "${rootDir}/A/B"
}
```

The above code works and creates an archive with name **ArchiveOfB.zip**. But this archive doesn't contain the directory B. The archive only contains the contents of directory B.

**Expected** content of zip file  **:**  A/B/contents-of-directory-B

**Actual** content of zip file **:** A/contents-of-directory-B

How do I go about getting the expected result. Any guidance in this regard is highly apprecited. i have looked up the "Working with fiels" section of Gradle documnetaion,but that doesn't help my cause. I was expecting some "include" property for including diretcories, but the include works only with files and no directory example was given.

Comment: you could simply configure the target directory within the archive, by adding `into ('B') ` in your  task definition. this will create a root level 'B' directory.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I have edited my question. corrected the formatting. used angular brackets to show "contents-of-directory-B". But that didn't work. So removed the brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `into` method (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:into(java.lang.Object) ) to specify the destination directory inside the archive

In you case you could do something like:

```
task ZipOnlyB(type: Zip){
    archiveName = "ArchiveOfB.zip"
    destinationDir = file ("${rootDir}/toSendToArtifactory")

    from  fileTree('A/B')
    into ('A/B')
}
```

This will create the archive with first level directory "A" containing the "B" directory and its content. If you don't want this root directory "A" but just directory "B", then use  `into ('B')`